# Spring Integration gateway proxy bean for <int:gateway> not being created

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have a context as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
  xmlns:int-amqp="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/amqp"
  xmlns:rabbit="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/amqp
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/amqp/spring-integration-amqp.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/spring-rabbit.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

  <int:gateway id="fooGateway" service-interface="com.foo.FooGateway"  />

</beans>
```

My gateway interface is as follows:

```
public interface FooGateway
{
    public void foo(String foo);
}
```

This context is imported into another context but the fooGateway bean is never created by GatewayProxyFactoryBean.

I've set a breakpoint in GatewayProxyFactoryBean and I can see that it is not creating a proxy for this interface.

Comment: Are you using the gateway anywhere (are you injecting it somewhere)? What happens? Is the injected gateway `null`, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Turn on DEBUG logging for `org.springframework`; the bean creation process emits lots of information including when it reads particular configuration files.